# Hidden input value to php session

Tags: javascript, php, forms, session

I have a form, which uses the following input towards the end:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ct_count" name="ct_count" value=""/>
```

The initialisation of the form is:

```
<form action="email_submission.php" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="mySubmit();">
```

And the mySubmit function is:

```
function mySubmit() {
  document.getElementById('ct_count').value = ct;
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
```

When i hit submit, I want to pass the value of ct, which is a variable count on the page, to email_submission.php and store it in a session variable. The session variable is returning blank on every submit, and i'm unsure if the value of the "ct" variable used is being passed through on the hidden field.

Is someone able to pick up where i'm going wrong? There are already variables stored correctly through this, so it's not my session settings as far as i know.

tldr: What's the correct way to take a javascript variable count and pass it through form submit to php?

EDIT: 
this is the code for adding fields.
intiial loop for the variable "ct"

```
function new_link()
{
ct++;
<?php $ct = $ct + 1; ?>

document.getElementById("sec4_lender").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_lender_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_balance").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_balance_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_termdate").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_lender_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_security").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_security_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_description").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_description_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_status").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_status_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_repayment").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_repayment_<?php echo $ct;?>');
document.getElementById("sec4_repayment2").setAttribute('name', 'sec4_repayment_2_<?php echo $ct;?>');

var div1 = document.createElement('tr');
div1.id = 'sect4busloan_div_'+ct+'';
// link to delete extended form elements
var delLink = '<tr style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px"><a href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Del</a></tr>';
div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML + delLink;
document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);

}

// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt(eleId)
{
d = document;
var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');
parentEle.removeChild(parentEle.childNodes[eleId]);
var newct = ct - 1;
ct = newct;
<?php $ct = $ct - 1;?>

}
```

Comment: make sure you have `session_start()` on page you r using them on

Comment: There is a session_start() at the beginning of every page.

Comment: And you've logged `ct` and know it has a value? The line submitting the form in the javascript should be uneccessary.

Comment: you are not printing session value in hidden field.. you should echo your session value there.

Comment: make sure session_start returns a boolean true. false = something failed, e.g. headers already sent. and if that appears ok, then confirm that `session_id()` is always returning the same value. different values = different (new/empty) sessions.

Comment: When you say the session variable is returning blank on every submit, what exactly do you mean? Do you receive the post parameter on the form submission?

Comment: Everything else in the form (it's a BIG form, so i'm not going to post it) goes through to the email script perfectly fine. There are three pages to it, and every page has a submit as well. Each time i move page, i store all the data in session variables. At the end page, it submits and emails the content.

Comment: Everything goes through absolutely fine except the loop number, which isn't being pulled through at all. It's just coming through as blank.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `document.getElementById('ct_count').value = ct;` and check the value of `ct`.

Comment: I added a document.write() to the submit function to see, and it is indeed incrementing. I need that variable CT to be placed into the hidden input as it's value.. but it's just not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that while bug testing i had moved that single session out of the conditionals for my script. So for every page other than the first i was moving on to, it was requesting a blank variable.

Idiocy at its finest. Thank you very much for everyone helping in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the input's value and always setting it to `ct` -

```
document.getElementById('ct_count').value = ct;
```

You should get a warning or error about `ct` in the console if you do it this. What you should do is set a variable to the value of the input -

```
var ct = document.getElementById('ct_count').value;
```

It also appears that you never set the value of the hidden field, so in the example I post here `ct`'s value will always be blank.

Comment: It's actually the opposite i'm trying to do. CT is the count of how many fields have been added. So i want on submission of the form, the hidden field to equal the value of the count.

Comment: How do you get that value @DanielRuxton?

Comment: When i click a button which says "add field", the function newlink increments the variable ct.

Comment: We need to see that code because the code you have posted will not tell us why the error is occurring @DanielRuxton

Comment: I cannot access that image from here @DanielRuxton. Please edit your original post to add any updated information. This will also help to preserve your code and question for future visitors to SO.

Comment: edittedin order to help you understand what's going.